# Enable ASLR in GDB

Tags: gdb, aslr

I know that GDB disables ASLR for applications it debugs.
Is there a way to enable ASLR inside GDB? I have a bug that I can only reproduce with ASLR enabled.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to enable ASLR inside GDB?

Yes:

```
(gdb) set disable-randomization off
```